# window scroll event is not firing up when overflow-y: scroll is set to some element in body

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please refer below sample html

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="parent">
..............
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS for parent element:

```
#parent
{
position: absolute;
    min-width: 1020px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 121px;
    bottom: 75px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

i am trying to use window scroll event like below

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
alert('triggered');
});
```

but scroll event is not firing up when i set overflow-y :scroll to parent element. when i remove this css(overflow) scroll event is firing up. so what is the correct behavior ? why window scroll event is not invoking when overflow css there ?

Comment: Try use `min-height: 2000px;` and check trigger event

Comment: @dbucki am asking why is not triggering when i use overflow-y css?

Comment: when you scroll, you don't scroll window but you scroll `#parent`

Comment: thanks i understood.need to add both min-height and overflow-y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to bind the event "scroll" with the #parent element.

```
$("#parent").on("scroll",function(){
    alert("Event Triggered!");
});
```

Anything let me know